# Sum element of numbers to get desired result

Tags: python, python-itertools

By using the snippet

```
import itertools
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
results = [7,8]
allcombs = [seq for i in range(len(numbers), 0, -1) for seq in itertools.combinations(numbers, i) if sum(seq) in results]

print(allcombs)
```

I'm able to get all combinations which give me the desire results. Major problem here is that the number must not repeat. So, instead of result

```
[(1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 5)]
```

I need to get

```
[(1, 2, 4),(3, 5)]
```

All elements of results doesnt needs to be contained in combination of numbers.

Edit:

## 1 Solution

```
usednumbers = []
newresult = []
for comb in allcombs:
    if not any(a in usednumbers for a in comb):
        newresult.append(comb)
        for n in comb:
            usednumbers.append(n)
            
print(newresult)
```

Comment: So you don't care if you get `[(1, 2, 4), (3, 5)]` or `[(3, 4), (1, 2, 5)]` or `[(2, 5), (1, 3, 4)]`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl correct. I dont care of order or which combination will be used to get it

Comment: Are the two lists guaranteed to sum up to the same total?

Comment: @schwobaseggl It may happen they dont have match at all

Comment: @schwobaseggl i managed to write solution by using two more for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a recursive function that will find the largest combination first and then call itself with the remaining numbers to add other combinations that match the results.

Also, the combinations should be generated with indexes in addition to the numbers themselves to make it easier to determine the remaining values when the list contains duplicates numbers.

```
from itertools import combinations

def comboToSums(numbers,results,size=None):
    if size is None: size = len(numbers)
    if size == 0: return []
    for combo in combinations(enumerate(numbers),size):
        indexes,values = zip(*combo)
        if sum(values) not in results: continue
        remaining = [n for i,n in enumerate(numbers) if i not in indexes]
        return [values] + comboToSums(remaining,results)
    return comboToSums(numbers,results,size-1)
```

output:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
results = [7,8]
c = comboToSums(numbers,results)
print(c) # [(1, 2, 4), (3, 5)]
```